# Debugging in SWI-prolog - unbound variables

Tags: debugging, prolog, dcg

Consider the following Prolog code.  It edits lines of a particular type in its input and prints out the remaining lines w/o any change.  It uses a DCG called `rule` which isn't included below, since it's not important to the question.

```
go:-
    prompt(_, ''),
    processInput.

processInput:-
    read_line_to_codes(current_input, Codes),
    processInput(Codes).

processInput(Codes):-
    (Codes \= end_of_file
    ->
        (phrase(rule(Part1, Part2), Codes)
        ->
            format('~s - ~s\n', [ Part1, Part2 ])
        ;
            format('~s\n', [ Codes ])),
        processInput
    ;
        true).

:- go, halt.
```

This works fine.  However, suppose I change `processInput/1` to the following, it just says that `Warning: /home/asfernan/tmp/tmp.pl:28:  Goal (directive) failed: user: (go,halt)`.

```
processInput(Codes):-
    (Codes \= end_of_file
    ->
        (\+phrase(rule(Part1, Part2), Codes)
        ->
            format('~s\n', [ Codes ]))
        ;
            format('~s - ~s\n', [ Part1, Part2 ]),
        processInput
    ;
        true).
```

The if & else parts of the `phrase(rule(Part1, Part2), Codes)` DCG match have been exchanged.  This is obviously a newbie mistake, but the fact that `go, halt` failed isn't very helpful.  What can I do to make the error message indicate that the failure was because `Part1` & `Part2` were not bound in the `format('~s - ~s\n', [ Part1, Part2 ])` line?  I was able to track down this error because the code is small, but I may not have been able to do so had the code been big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Prolog the following is not the same:

```
..., ( Cond -> Then ; Else ), ...
```

and

```
..., ( \+ Cond -> Else ; Then ), ...
```

In general, a goal `\+ Cond` will never instantiate its variables. So you
have to stick to the original formulation.

In case you are interested to process entire
files with DCGs, consider SWI's `library(pio)`.